# Bad experience with NEAR Protocol development tools

Tags: nearprotocol

During Blockchain Hackathon Kyiv 2020 we picked NEAR Protocol challenge and found several issues.

1. Accound and account keys are created in web wallet. Then you should run "near login" command at your server which should launch curl to web wallet and authorize near-cli app for accessing keys. However in our case keys weren't imported into server deployed at Digital Ocean with Ubuntu 20.0.4 and accessed via console. Near Discord channel didn't responded to our questions at all. Telegram devs chat support guys didn't helped much, their last offer was "copy keys from localstorage to json file and put into your server .near-credentials folder"

But after all - and that was amazing - a new key created at those remote machine with near addkey command - was added to those accoundID which was not authorized to use app!!! :D

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yraia.png)

https://examples.near.org/ - GITPOD links doesn't properly configured, not working with errors

https://gitpod.io/#https://github.com/near-examples/token-contract-as
https://gitpod.io/#https://github.com/near-examples/wallet-example

Comment: Aaand your question is?

Answer (score 3):

Excited that you chose to build on NEAR, but disheartened to hear about your subpar experience. NEAR is currently growing at an exponential rate and engineering resources certainly can be limited at times.

Unfortunately, if you created your NEAR account on a different machine than the one you want to store the credentials for that account on, running `near login` won't work. You could get around this by copying your private key from your browser's local storage to the remote machine's browser's local storage, *then* running `near login` on that machine but thats a little more work than what’s necessary. The easier, more straightforward path, would be to run `near login` on your local machine (the one that created the NEAR account) and copy the newly created `.json` file located in `~/.near-credentials` to the target machine. I think that’s what the devs on Telegram you chatted with were referring to. Currently, that would be the easiest solution to that issue.

> But after all - and that was amazing - a new key created at those remote machine with near addkey command - was added to those accoundID which was not authorized to use app!!! :D

Could you clarify what exactly happened here and how you performed this action? You should not be able to add a full access key to an account without an existing full access key.

Also, thank you for raising our attention to the two broken GitPod examples. There have been several updates recently to the `near-sdk-as` dependency these two projects rely on, and looks like something broke. I will make sure this is resolved ASAP!

Please let me know if you have any other questions, comments, or suggestions, and thank you so much for bearing with us as we continue to enhance our platform and developer tooling.

Comment: I created account at https://wallet.testnet.near.org/ via Chrome/Win10 machine. Than I deployed Ubuntu 20.0.4 at Digital Ocean cloud and installed near-cli on it. As 'near login' didn't worked I tried several other commands including 'near addkey'. And 3rd key appeared at web wallet :D

Answer (score 1):

> Near Discord channel didn't responded to our questions at all. Telegram devs chat support guys didn't helped much, their last offer was "copy keys from localstorage to json file and put into your server .near-credentials folder"

I would like to point out that there is no paid service with 24/7 support. People have their weekends to spend with their family and friends.

> But after all - and that was amazing - a new key created at those remote machine with near addkey command - was added to those accoundID which was not authorized to use app!!!

Which key are you talking about? The 3 keys you have on the screenshot were sequentially used to sign the next transaction adding the new key:

1. [`ETQeNJrRiqbcuqJyrfDTh1EYAUAetXZsnuuiEH8T6mnc` transaction](https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/ETQeNJrRiqbcuqJyrfDTh1EYAUAetXZsnuuiEH8T6mnc) created the account with `ed25519:HBi7mgC...` key.
2. [`8heaysv121qhFjktwRm9ftF4jA7dgcYRHvKkcCnhXFVT` transaction](https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/8heaysv121qhFjktwRm9ftF4jA7dgcYRHvKkcCnhXFVT) signed with `ed25519:HBi7mgC...` key (added in (1)) adds a new `ed25519:DmNJSxx...` full-access key.
3. [`DUp8VJ9aoUyC6r8ira6udpgHYxsKJWi3LXkxxn5btLW2` transaction](https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/DUp8VJ9aoUyC6r8ira6udpgHYxsKJWi3LXkxxn5btLW2) signed with `ed25519:DmNJSxx...` key (added in (2)) adds a new `ed25519:DoMh6uC...` full-access key.